# Copying a chain

Tags: python, copy, python-itertools

I noticed some weird behaviour when I `copy.copy` an `itertools.chain`:

```
from copy import copy
from itertools import chain
```

When I exhaust one of them the result is as expected:

```
>>> a = chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
>>> b = copy(a)
>>> list(a), list(b)
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [])

>>> a, b = chain_and_copy()
>>> list(b), list(a)
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [])
```

However when I use `next` the results seem odd:

```
>>> a = chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
>>> b = copy(a)
>>> next(a), list(b), list(a)
(1, [4, 5, 6], [2, 3])   # b "jumps" to the second iterable...

>>> a = chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
>>> next(a)
1
>>> b = copy(a)
>>> next(a), next(b), next(a)
(2, 3, 4)
>>> next(b)   # b is empty
StopIteration:
>>> next(a)   # a is not empty
5
```

Is that a Bug or is shallow copying an iterator generally a bad idea? I noticed that a copy of `iter` and a copy of `zip` behave differently too:

```
>>> a = zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
>>> b = copy(a)
>>> next(a), next(b)
((1, 4), (2, 5))  # copies share the same "position"

>>> a = iter([1,2,3])
>>> b = copy(a)
>>> next(a), next(b)
(1, 1)   # copies don't share the same "position"
```

Comment: use `tee` to "copy" your generator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315207/deep-copying-a-generator-in-python

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826746/pythonic-way-of-copying-an-iterable-object

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually I expected something that works like a shallow copy of `zip` (shares position between iterators). That's not really achievable using `itertools.tee`, `copy.deepcopy` or `pickle`. If I wanted a deep copy I wouldn't have used a shallow copy operation `copy.copy` to begin with :)

Comment: I didn't close the question because I had a doubt and you know a lot about python & SO already. But I wouldn't copy an iterator. I read some Q&A (cannot find it now) which explained that it's bound to fail. iterators can be a lot of different things. Some have the `__next__` attribute, some haven't... I'm no expert but I feel that it's XY problem :)

Comment: Well, the question is about the root-cause for a bug I was trying to debug and fix. So yes, maybe an XY problem because the answer seems to be "[...] I wouldn't copy an iterator. I read some Q&A (cannot find it now) which explained that it's bound to fail.".

Comment: not a lot of people can answer that one. good luck (my short answer to "Is that a Bug or is shallow copying an iterator generally a bad idea?" is yes BTW :))

Answer (score 3):

You are just confused by miss using the nested iterables and simple iterables.

Regarding the `copy` and the your first example you just need to use `deepcopy` in order to create a proper copy of your iterable:

```
In [87]: a = chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6])

In [88]: b = deepcopy(a)

In [89]: list(a)
Out[89]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [90]: list(b)
Out[90]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And there is no special thing about `next` too. Here is the equivalent of `chain` function from python documentation:

```
def chain(*iterables):
    # chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            yield element
```

As you can see, the first `for` is looping over the iterables which in this case are `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]` so if you just copy the generator object and actually create a shallow copy of it, each call to the `next` in first place will consume one of the iterables, then it iterates over the iterable items. So when you call the `next(a)` it already consumed the first iterable, and that's why `list(b)` returns the `[4, 5, 6]`.

And again if you use `deepcopy` you won't see this behavior anymore.

```
In [94]: a = chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6])

In [95]: b = deepcopy(a)

In [96]: next(a), list(b), list(a)
Out[96]: (1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

This is also true for `zip`, since you are passing multiple iterable to the function. And if you use `deepcopy` you'll end up with different objects:

```
In [100]: a = zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])

In [101]: b = deepcopy(a)

In [102]: next(a), next(b)
Out[102]: ((1, 4), (1, 4))
```

But the `copy` works fine for `iter` since you're just passing one iterable to the function and there is no need to `deepcopy`.

After all, the best (most pythonic) way for copying a generator is using `itertools.tee`:

```
In [103]: from itertools import tee

In [104]: a = zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])

In [105]: a, b = tee(a)

In [106]: list(a)
Out[106]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

In [107]: list(b)
Out[107]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

In [108]: 

In [108]: a = chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6])

In [109]: a, b = tee(a)

In [110]: list(a)
Out[110]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [111]: list(b)
Out[111]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It makes sense, however I don't get the point about passing in multiple iterables. It may be splitting hairs but I pass in the iterables as themselves `chain(a, b)` or `zip(a, b)` so why would I expect a shallow copy not to copy the iterators themselves? I wouldn't expect it if I passed them in as data-structure like `chain([a, b])` or `zip([a, b])` (these don't work obviously, just to illustrate the point). However python-generators are a completly different topic because they can't be copied anyway. But am I right that you mean "don't shallow copy iterators!"?

Comment: As a matter of fact `a, b` is a tuple. But is has nothing to do with the way you should copy the iterator that's because of the way that `copy` works. I'm also  not saying that don't shallow copy the iterators. Functions like  `chain` and `zip` which iterates over the iterables first can not be copy properly by using the `copy` function, like a nested list.

Comment: @MSeifert Nevertheless, if you're not satisfied yet, you should check out the `copy` and `deepcopy`'s source to see how they actually work. I'm not exactly sure how the `copy` deals with iterator object.